# How to refer to a properties file in a batch file

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, batch-file

I'm trying to run my Java program using a batch file, I'm able to run it properly. However, when I run the batch file after inserting the code to read a properties file from the Java program, I'm getting the following error.

```
     Can't find bundle for base name app1, locale en_US
```

Actually i have a conf folder under which I have this properties folder, then I came to know that I need to keep this conf folder in the class path. But I have actually added it as class folder using Eclipse. However, I'm getting the same error. Please let me know what exactly I need to do for running the Java program using batch file. Using Eclipse I'm able to run the properly.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. `then I came to know that I need to keep this conf folder in the class path`. Did you add the `/conf/` folder to the classpath that is executing Java from the batch file?

Comment: please tell me how to add the conf folder in the class path

Comment: can you post the section of your batch script where you are executing your Java application?

Comment: @echo off


java    -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -classpath ./bin    com.myapp.app1.demoprogram

 
pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments your batch script:

```
@echo off
java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -classpath ./bin com.myapp.app1.demoprogram
pause
```

Notice how the `/conf/` directory is not listed on the classpath. The easiest way to get it there is to just add it to the `-classpath` argument being passed to the JVM. Something closer to:

```
@echo off
java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -classpath ./bin;./conf com.myapp.app1.demoprogram
pause
```

This is assuming that /conf/ is in the same directory as bin. You might have to do some tweaking to get the setup to work for you application, but the root problem is that while you added the `/conf/` folder to the project classpath in eclipse, you need to do the same thing for the batch script so the JVM can find it

Comment: hi actually, i have two files in the conf folder, one Im able to pull it up using batch file, but with the other file(i.e for stconfig.xml), Im not able to do so as Im getting the following error "stconfig.xml not found as a resource", any idea boss